# How do i make a program that generate's a list of recommended anime?

Tags: python

This is my first time i am doing programming and using stack overflow.

For the program i am doing, it generates a list of anime recommendations by going through a survey style questions. Having a CSV file storing info about the anime such as the genre and the number of episodes it has in it.

I'm hoping if i am doing the program correctly and that i can make it more better than the one i made. Honestly, seeking for advice, help and guidance. By the way, I am using Python as well.

Here's what i have done far:

```
import csv

#in the csv AnimeGenre3.csv it contains information such as the animes, the number of episodes and genres

#printing information about the program.
#has an if statement to identify if it user wants to start the program.

looping1 = True

print('This is a program that identifies specfic anime for you')

while looping1 == True:
    begin = str(input('Do you like to start; yes or no: '))
    
    if begin == 'yes':
        print('''
Let's begin
''')
        break
    if begin == 'no':
        print('thank you for coming')
    else:
        print('''
    Sorry Man got to do it again
            ''')
#this section is where the program ask the user questions from there
# it will identify, the genres the user is interested in.
looping2 = True

while looping2 == True:
    
    action = str(input('Do you like action; yes or no: '))
    adventure = str(input('Do you like adventure; yes or no: '))
    comedy = str(input('Do you like comedy; yes or no: '))
    documentary = str(input('Do you like documentary; yes or no: '))
    drama = str(input('Do you like drama; yes or no: '))
    fanservice = str(input('Do you like fan service; yes or no: '))
    fantasy = str(input('Do you like fantasy; yes or no: '))
    gaming = str(input('Do you like gaming; yes or no: '))
    historical = str(input('Do you like historical; yes or no: '))
    horror = str(input('Do you like horror; yes or no: '))
    idol = str(input('Do you like idol; yes or no: '))
    isekai = str(input('Do you like isekai; yes or no: '))
    kids = str(input('Do you like kids; yes or no: '))
    magicalgirl = str(input('Do you like magical girl; yes or no: '))
    martialarts = str(input('Do you like matrtial arts; yes or no: '))
    mecha = str(input('Do you like mecha; yes or no: '))
    mystery = str(input('Do you like mystery; yes or no: '))
    romance = str(input('Do you like romance; yes or no: '))
    school = str(input('Do you like school; yes or no: '))
    scifi = str(input('Do you like sci fi; yes or no: '))
    shonen = str(input('Do you like shonen; yes or no: '))
    sliceoflife = str(input('Do you like slice of life; yes or no: '))
    space = str(input('Do you like space; yes or no: '))
    sports = str(input('Do you like sport; yes or no: '))
    superpower = str(input('Do you like super power; yes or no: '))
    supernatual = str(input('Do you like supernatual; yes or no: '))
    magic = str(input('Do you like magic; yes or no: '))
    physiochogical = str(input('Do you like physichogical; yes or no: '))
    thriller = str(input('Do you like thriller; yes or no: '))
    print('')
    print('Recommended Anime List:')
   #having to use if statements to find any anime that either say "yes" in the csv file
    # it sorts out all of the sorts that the useer said yes to.
    # It goes through the rows to identify all of user genres that say yes
    # it should print out the recommend anime
    # this prints out a long list of anime
    
    if action == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[3] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False
                    print(' *', anime)
         
    if adventure == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[4] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False
                    print(' *', anime)
    
    if comedy == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[5] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if documentary == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[7] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if drama == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[8] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if fanservice == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[9] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
    
    if fantasy == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[10] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if gaming == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[11] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if historical == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[12] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if horror == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[13] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if idol == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[14] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if isekai == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[15] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if kids == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[16] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if magicalgirl == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[17] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if martialarts == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[18] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if mecha == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[19] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if mystery == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[20] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if romance == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[21] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if school == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[22] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if scifi == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[23] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if shonen == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[24] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if sliceoflife == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[25] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if space == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[26] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if sports == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[27] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if superpower == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[28] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if supernatual == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[29] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if magic == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[30] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if physiochogical == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[31] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
                    
    if thriller == 'yes':
        with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", 'r', newline='') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[32] == 'yes':
                    anime = str(row[1])
                    looping = False        
                    print(' *', anime)
    else:
        print('''
    There seems to be a problem in one of the questions
            ''')
    # if there is an sytax error within the program, it should pop up to the user saying this
        
    StartAgain = str(input('Do you like to start again; yes or no: '))
    
    if StartAgain == 'yes':
        print('''
Let's begin
''')
        break
    if StartAgain == 'no':
        print('thank you for coming')
    
    else:
        print('''
    Sorry Man got to do it again''')
    
    # an if statement if user wants to start again
    # this should run the program again.
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Also any advice or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: If there's no actual problem, this belongs on the Code Review Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: thanks for the advice but i was also wondering how do i stop the characters or names from duplicating @AKX

Comment: @zabop did my explanation make sense

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactoring of your code to use a list of genres, a set to keep track of what the user likes, and two loops to just print out the matching items in the file. It will not print duplicates since the file is read only once, not once for each liked genre.

Since I'm using f-strings here, you'll need Python 3.6+.

```
import csv

genres = [  # Genres, in same order as the flags in the CSV file
    "action",
    "adventure",
    "comedy",
    "documentary",
    "drama",
    "fanservice",
    "fantasy",
    "gaming",
    "historical",
    "horror",
    "idol",
    "isekai",
    "kids",
    "magicalgirl",
    "martialarts",
    "mecha",
    "mystery",
    "romance",
    "school",
    "scifi",
    "shonen",
    "sliceoflife",
    "space",
    "sports",
    "superpower",
    "supernatual",
    "magic",
    "physiochogical",
    "thriller",
]

# Set up an empty set for the user's preferences.
liked_genres = set()

# Loop over all known genres; enumerate() will give us the ordinal
# of each genre too, to add a "progress indicator" for the user.
for i, genre in enumerate(genres, 1):
    # If the user's input starts with an "y", assume it's a like.
    liked_this = (
        input(f"{i} / {len(genres)}: Do you like {genre}; yes or no: ")
        .lower()
        .startswith("y")
    )
    # If it's a like, add the genre to the set.
    if liked_this:
        liked_genres.add(genre)

# Print out the set for confirmation.
print(f"You like: {liked_genres}")

# Compute the CSV column indices for each liked genre.
liked_genre_csv_indices = [3 + genres.index(genre) for genre in liked_genres]

with open("AnimeGenre3.csv", "r", newline="") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        # If any of the liked indices is true, then print the title.
        if any(row[index] == "yes" for index in liked_genre_csv_indices):
            anime = str(row[1])
            print(" *", anime)
```

Comment: sorry for the most dumbest question but where do i download Python 3.6 also do i need to pay for it. @AKX Thanks

Comment: Python is completely free. You can download the latest version [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
However, if you have a python version > 3.6 you don't need to download a new version to run the code above.
You can find which python version you have with this code : `import sys; print(sys.version) `

Comment: @asianpanda: please do carefully read this code and understand the concepts behind this answer. Do not just copy/paste it. As you can see, this is a major improvement, giving you dozens of variables less. If you want to become a serious developer, you *must* know those concepts

Comment: How would i layout my CSV file

Comment: This code is compatible with your current CSV file.

Comment: @AKX thank you also how would i layout my csv file and also where do i place a syntax error incase i put in something other than "no" or "yes"?

Comment: @AKX how would you put this in                                                                             
StartAgain = str(input('Do you like to start again; yes or no: '))
    
    if StartAgain == 'yes':
        print('''
Let's begin
''')
        break
    if StartAgain == 'no':
        print('thank you for coming')
    
    else:
        print('''
    Sorry Man got to do it again''')

Comment: You could wrap the entire genre-asking-and-suggestion-printing process in a function, then call it repeatedly in a `while` loop.